# "Aliasing" `ls` to `gls`

Tags: dired, shell-command, path, local-variables, exec-path

### `gls` not `ls`:

My system has two forms of `ls`, the standard "old school" version of `ls`, and GNU `ls` which is available as `gls`. In my shell, I simply created an alias to use `gls`, but I have not found a way to create the same alias for emacs. As you can probably guess, this impacts my use of dired, which relies on the availability of GNU ls. How do I get emacs to recognize and use the `gls` instead of `ls`?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert-directory-program is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.

Its value is "ls"

Absolute or relative name of the ‘ls’-like program.
This is used by ‘insert-directory’ and ‘dired-insert-directory’
(thus, also by ‘dired’).

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
```

Hence:

```el
(setq insert-directory-program "gls")
```

Comment: Confirmed! That worked. No more error messages about `ls --dired`. Hooray!!! On OpenBSD `gls` is exactly the same as calling `ls` on Linux. It is one of the catches programmers often run into when attempting to write code for both Linux and OpenBSD. I am so happy! Happy Dance Time!!!

Comment: I'm glad that did the trick.  Given that particular error, though, you should also look at `C-h v dired-use-ls-dired`.  By my reading, its default value *should* have been avoiding that error; so if that user option was set to its default value *and* failing to correctly detect the situation, then you should `M-x report-emacs-bug` so that the detection could be improved.

Comment: That said, in order to figure out whether or not to use the `--dired` option, `dired-insert-directory` simply runs `ls --dired` behind the scenes and checks whether or not that produced an error, which seems like it ought to be reliable; so I'd think that either the `ls` implementation is behaving in unexpected ways, or you had that user option customized to enforce the `--dired` usage.

Comment: I believe that using `gls` is still going to be the most reliable option, though, so I'm not suggesting that you revert that change.

Comment: I believe the latter was the case. Saying this, I was aware of the ls-lisp option, but did not want to "settle" for it when there was no reason to, and have been meaning to "fix" the issue for an unreasonable amount of time.

Comment: I was in the process of configuring ls-lisp, ls-lisp+, and files+ when I decided to check the board first. I am thankful I did. In the past, I either had the variable set to ls-lisp or was too stubborn to do it.  I recently cleaned my init file, which explains why the error now came to life.